# Asking permission

Tags: expressions

If you want to enter someone's bedroom and you want to avoid unpleasant situations(they're changing their clothes,for example) what would you say?

Comment: "I'm so sorry. I should not have come into your bedroom at all to begin with. What was I thinking?"

Comment: Start by knocking, then say something like "Hey, can I come in?"

Comment: is it polite enough?

Comment: What I suggested is somewhat informal -- use it with a friend, a roommate, etc. if you're trying to enter your boss's bedroom or something, for some reason, then you should say something more like "Hi, it's [your name]. Is this a good time for me to [reason you have to enter]?"

Answer (score 1):

You can simply knock on the door and wait to be invited. If they respond "Hello?" that may not be an invitation to enter, merely to announce yourself and why you wish to enter.

You could state your intentions:

> May I come in and... (do whatever it is you need access to their room to do)?

I assume, of course, that you have a good reason for entering their room!

If you particularly want to check if they are appropriately clothed, etc., you could ask:

> Are you [decent](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/decent)?

Although is is safer to be more explicit that you want to come in rather than assuming you have the right to enter their room whenever they're clothed.

Answer (score 0):

One strategy is to feign complete ignorance. Knock on the door, and say

> "Knock, knock? Anyone in there?"

This avoids the need to ask any specific question. Asking "Are you decent?" is for some a bit personal, especially if you are not on close terms. After all, it suggests that you have been considering the possibility that he or she is *not* decent.

Comment: Probably if you're creeping around a relative stranger's bedroom you're gonna come off as weird at best, but I agree that asking whether or not the person is dressed is just icing on the cake. I gotta wonder what OP plans on doing with these sentences, but... at least OP is asking permission to enter and not just barging in I guess?